# Sql command doesn't display table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code behind button that displays table in SQL when the button is pressed.
I cant seem to know that problem why it doesn't display any table?

I added this line of code to check if the BatchID is out of range in the sql table

```
   if (read.Read())
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = read;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "BatchID out of range";
    }


   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() =="ER00 - File Header")
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBcon"]))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_ID.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "Please enter BatchID!";

                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "";
                        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader Where BatchID =" + TextBox_ID.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCommand.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        if (read.Read())
                        {
                            GridView1.DataSource = read;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "BatchID out of range";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {                           

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: FYI, you've got some bad habits in that code. Don't ever ignore exceptions - you'll like it when you can find out what's wrong and fix it. Also, your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: that doesn't even answer my question

Comment: @user1954418: You must provide more information in your question, try to change your `catch` block to this: `catch(Exception exc)` then put the code in your `catch` block: MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

Comment: its very bad idea to hard code the parameters in the command text and your code is prone to sql injection. Try using [SqlPramater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to avoid such hack

Comment: And one small thing - your code would look a lot cleaner if you changed the "if" to  `if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() !="ER00 - File Header"){return;}`

Comment: @user: I know it doesn't solve today's problem. That's why I told you they were bad habits. Nobody's forcing you to break bad habits.

Comment: You are advised not to hide exceptions because it is likely your problem. For example, if `BatchID` is a string field, then you need to quote the value in your `where` clause (which should have been parameterized). Without it `ExecuteReader` throws an exception, but you have no means to see it. `MessageBox` may not be the best way, instead you can simply remove/comment `try/catch` for now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do two things.

1.) Close the `DataReader` after `Databind()`.

2.) Set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` for your `GridView`.